# What is the best way to subscribe to NEW questions with a given tag?

Tags: support

I know you can subscribe using

feed://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/cocoa

but this seems to give active questions. I am only interested in new questions. How can I subscribe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way of getting the newest questions for a specific tag is the RSS feed. Here's a cocoa example:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=cocoa&sort=newest

Notice the get parameters.